# Make form_button in codeigniter to act as an anchor

Tags: codeigniter

According to the CI Library there are 2 parameters for the form_button using form_helper. I can use the thrd parameter to give the button a class. But I want to also give the button a PATH so it acts like an anchor.
Is there an option for this? How else could I anchor it using form_helper not html?

```
form_button('name', 'content', 'class');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but:

A form_button() function creates an

```
<input type="submit" />
```

tag, which does not have something like src attribute where you can give a certain path.

If you want it to look like a link, you can style that with CSS. 
If you want to use `<a href="..">` link to submit the form, you can use jQuery to achieve that.
If you want to submit the form to a specific URL (what you refer to as PATH), you can specify that in the `form_open()` function.

Comment: ah it creates a submit type. I see. Thanks for that!